# How to create and retrieve ng-model value inside ng-repeat in an Ionic view?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

this is my IONIC view

```
  <div class="divTable" ng-repeat="quest in Questions" >
  <div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell" ><strong>{{quest.no}}.</strong></div>
  <div class="divTableCell" style="width:100%"><strong>{{quest.question}}</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow" ng-repeat="choice in quest.jawaban" >
  <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="divTableCell"><input type="radio"  ng-value="'{{choice.jawaban}}'" name="{{quest.no}}" id="{{choice.jawaban}}"><label for="{{choice.jawaban}}">{{choice.jawaban}}</label></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  </div>
  </div>
```

How to get radio button value in controller..?

Thank you

Comment: Can u update your controller, json data and mention the ng-model value

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="data" ng-value="'{{choice.jawaban}}'" name="{{quest.no}}" id="{{choice.jawaban}}">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.data = "start"; //will be the first selected, has to match any value
```

You can then use $scope.data to your whims or watch changes to it.

Comment: testing to console and the result is undefined